# how to fix Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect on glassfish server

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pool

i'm trying to create a connection pool and JDBC Resource to deploy a java application on glassfish server, however, I couldn't deploy the project, and this is what it said:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app :
> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
> 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
> Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection.
> Cause: The connection could not be allocated: Cannot open
> file:C:\Users\nguye\GlassFish_Server500\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
> [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect] Error Code: 0.
> Please see server.log for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Just try adding
`?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false` to you database on NetBeans as well as on connection pool URL.